# Using CustomPainter with isComplex and willChange in flutter

Tags: flutter

I using CustomPainter with 2 properties: **isComplex and willChange**.

There is no difference between using them and not.

please tell me the difference between them.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      isComplex: true,
      willChange: false,
      painter: MyPainter(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size.width; ) {
      Color color = Colors.green;
      if ((i/10)%2==0){
        color = Colors.red;
      }
      Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
          i + 10.0, size.height / 3, size.width / 10, size.height / 3);
      canvas.drawRect(rect, Paint()..color = color);
      i +=10;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Next, I've tried to change value of **isComplex and willChange**, there is no differences.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? whats your goal?

Comment: @pskink: I want to see the difference in case I change the value of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the documentation of [CustomPaint class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) which is a subclass of `CustomPainter`:

> **isComplex** and **willChange** are hints to the compositor's raster cache
>   and must not be null.

[isComplex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint/isComplex.html):

> Whether the painting is complex enough to benefit from caching.
>
> The compositor contains a raster cache that holds bitmaps of layers in
>   order to avoid the cost of repeatedly rendering those layers on each
>   frame. If this flag is not set, then the compositor will apply its own
>   heuristics to decide whether the this layer is complex enough to
>   benefit from caching.

[willChange](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint/willChange.html):

> Whether the raster cache should be told that this painting is likely
>   to change in the next frame.

So, basically you won't see any visual changes but handling them correctly will improve the use of the cache which will improve the rendering cost.